# Spark IDF for new documents

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

What is the best approach to apply tf.idf transformation to new documents in spark. I have a setting in which I train the model offline and then load it and apply it for new files. Basically, it does not make much sense to calculate IDF if there is no access to the model IDF distribution.

So far the only solution I thought of is to save the TF RDD of the training set and append the new doc to it and then calcualte IDF RDD and extract the new file from the IDF RDD. The problem with this is that I have to keep the entire TF vector in memory (I guess it could probably be down with the IDF RDD as well).

This looks like a problem someone already had, so looking for advice an insights in what is the best way to do it.

Cheers,

Ilija

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need RDDs at all. TF doesn't depend on anything else than a data you have (and vocabulary if you use fixed size representation without hashing) and IDF is simply a model which can be represented as a vector and depends only on vocabulary.

So the only thing you have to be kept around is an `IDFModel`. Assuming transformations you use look more or less like this:

```scala
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(rdd) 

val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
```

the only which is useful for further operations on the new data is the `idf` variable. While it has no `save` method it is a local serializable object so you can use standard Java methods to serialize it.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. Thanks. So IDFModel stores all the idf frequncies for the training set, right.

Comment: It does. IDF is only a single number per token in a vocabulary. You can even extract it using `idf.idf`

Comment: @zero323 Can you provide an example on how to use `IDF` with a new input. Do we still need to transform with `tf`? I'm thinking: `val newInput = new HashingTF().transform(newInputRDD) val newTfIdf = if.transform(newInput)` Will this give me the new mapping of my text to the same feature space used by my previously trained model?

Comment: Looks OK, I would reuse HashingTF as well. It doesn't depend on th data but it is still tunable.

Comment: Yep looks ok. You can reuse the HashingTF class if you have it. But in most cases training is going to be separate from actual application. You need to do tf transformation to get the TFs of the new document(s).

Comment: If I understand correctly you definitely use same training idfModel for prediction (with new set of documents) later but do you also use same training idfModel during validation? i.e. do you split your data before generating idfModel. Then generate idf on training data and use the same for both training and validation data?

Comment: @zero323 I am using `java.io.{FileOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}` to store the IDFModel but when loading it with `FileInputStream` etc. it doesnt seem to be serialized. (gives serialization error). can u elaborate how to store the idf model? thanks

Comment: I have the same question: How can I serialize the the IDF model? Is it also possible to do the same thing in pyspark, not scala?